# Curl fetch only headers without head

Tags: http, http-headers, curl

On our company servers due to security purposes our main SysAdmin only allows a few HTTP methods to pass through like (`GET`, `POST`, `OPTIONS`, `PUT`, etc.) and `HEAD` is not one of them.

I implemented `Zabbix` Monitoring on them to check if it pings correctly and if domain is down or not. What I do now is getting all response header and response body and check if it returns 200 OK or not.

The problem is due to many requests per second and timeouts I get lots of false errors therefore I don't want to waste my bandwidth to fetch all response header and response body just to check if a website is down or not and because of `HEAD` not allowed I can't do something like `curl -I` (which sends a `HEAD` `HTTP` request and only fetches response header so I could check if it returns 200 OK).

How can I send `GET HTTP` request but only fetch response header via curl?

Comment: Here is my command that will return all relevant information and exclude the body: `curl --connect-timeout 60 -v -I -X GET -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "https://google.com" 2>&1 | egrep -v '^> |^< |^{|^}|^* TLS|^* AL|^  0' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re afraid that your site can’t handle the load from your monitoring tool you’ve  got bigger issues to worry about IMHO...

But rather than retrieving the  main (large) index page simply **create a unlikely URL path with an empty file** and use that for monitoring.

Monitor for instance `http://www.example.com/wfujhtdvbhujnngre/fghbbvffvgghpoiklmx/status.txt`

That has the added benefit that to prevent inflated page view numbers requests for that URL path can easily be excluded when generating visitor stats.

Comment: I shouldn't really said "server load" (I changed my question), becuase that's my least concern. I was more trying to save bandwidth of monitoring server as there are lots of servers and I get lots of false alarms which many of them is because of timeout.
I want to decrease request and response size so maybe I can prevent this issue.

Comment: I took your advice and now I monitor domain/robots.txt. Thanks.